# Como validar o resultado de um Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como validar o resultado de um Case

Estou pegando o intervalo entre duas datas em dias, quero validar se o resultado e maior que 120 dias, tem uma forma melhor a que estou fazendo?

```
DECLARE @DataInicioVigencia datetime; -- ='2018-11-30T00:00:00'; 
DECLARE @DataInicioVigenciaProgramada datetime = '2018-11-30T00:00:00'; 
DECLARE @DataAdmissao       datetime = '2018-07-01T00:00:00';  

select
   CASE 
     WHEN isdate(@DataInicioVigencia) = 1 AND 
          (  ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@DataInicioVigencia,@DataAdmissao)) > 120 ) then 1
     WHEN isdate(@DataInicioVigenciaProgramada) = 1 AND 
          ( ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@DataInicioVigenciaProgramada,@DataAdmissao)) > 125 ) then 2
   ELSE 3
   END as 'PRAZO'
from FUNCIONARIOS

--mostrar o cálculo
select ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@DataInicioVigencia,@DataAdmissao))
select ABS(DATEDIFF(day,@DataInicioVigenciaProgramada,@DataAdmissao))
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? O CASE que utiliza não está retornando resultado correto?

Comment: Tem certeza que precisa desse ABS?

Comment: Gostaria de saber se tem alguma opção melhor para fazer o que preciso

Comment: @Marconi, o valor pode vim negativo, por isso o ABS

Comment: Esse `ABS` pode dar aso a resultados errados, visto que 120 a mais é bem diferente de 120 dias a menos! O `ISDATE` também não me parece necessário porque se o tipo é `DATETIME` a validação dá sempre `true` (a não ser que possa ser `NULL`, mas aí pode fazer `ISNULL` para validar). Mas em relação ao `CASE`, não vejo qualquer problema.